# I wrote the first project from the Django site, it does not issue an error, but when I go to the browser, it only shows the picture of the rocket

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDxoq.jpg)
I imported the code from the first Django site project and expected the Django function codes to run in the browser, but they all show rocket images.  Do I need to install a specific item or program?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to activate the Auto save option, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the rocket it means u have succesfully created Django project what you have not done is configure url views.py and urls.py and create tempalets floder having home.html file or any html file i write it down in steps

Step 1 : Setting.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        '[your app name without brackets with quoteations]',    
        ...
        
    
    ]


 
Under Templates in settings.py  Update the 'DIRS' section also make sure to create a template folder in your App 

        TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': ['templates'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Step 2 : Create a view in view.py eg:

```
def home (request):
    return render(request, "home.html")
```

Step 3 : Create urls.py file in your app and write

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("", home, name="home"),
]
```

Step 4 : Update your website/project urls.py and write

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('App.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

Step 5 : Create a html named home.html in this case 
Step 6 : Run server using

```
python manage.py runserver
py manage.py runserver
```